# Selenium WebDriver ImplicitWait is ignored

Tags: selenium, webdriver, wait

I am currently following this tutorial on Selenium Waits: [click me](https://courses.ultimateqa.com/courses/take/synchronization-techniques/lessons/262469-00-introduction-and-pre-reqs/)

I cannot for the life of me figure out why my ImplicitWait is just being ignored.

```
        private void TryFind()
    {
        _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        //go to a url that contains a dynamically loading page element
        _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URI);
        //click the start button
        _driver.FindElement(By.TagName("button")).Click();
        //find the element that has the text Hello World
        var text = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[contains(text(),'Hello World!')]"));
        //click on the text
        text.Click();
    }
```

I am expecting this to wait for 5 seconds before clicking the element, but it's just rushing and throwing an exception.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Can you share the exception? And on which element is the exception thrown?

Comment: Which Selenium Client are you using? Java/C#/Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it was a Selenium bug - I raised it with the tutorial author and he has raised a bug against it: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5044

JeffC, points noted - thank you. Debugging it something I’m still getting used to but I’ll try and give more info next time.